# Groovy script is working in script console but not in build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a groovy script which works in the script console but not in my pipeline when I call it as groovy script (it's coming from my shared library):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.*
import hudson.*
import java.lang.*

def call(String jobname, String build_string) {
  echo "Hello, ${jobname}."
  echo "Hello, ${build_string}."

  //Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class).each { println(it.fullName) };

  def job = Jenkins.instance.items.find { it.name == 'test' }
  echo "Hello, ${job}."

    for (build in job.builds) {
        def log = build.log
        if (log.contains('hey')) {
            println "${job.name}: ${build.id}"
        }
    }
}
```

I use some hardcoded variables to be sure, I have a job named 'test' and it contains ('hey') in the output. Then the jobname and buildid is printed and this is working fine in the script console.

But when I call it in the pipeline with: `filterOutput env.JOB_NAME , 'a'` I get:

```
[test] Running shell script
+ echo hey
hey
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (getOutput)
[Pipeline] echo
Hello, test.
[Pipeline] echo
Hello, a.
[Pipeline] echo
Hello, false.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: builds for class: java.lang.Boolean
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:33)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this working in my console and not in my build?

Comment: what java versions do you use? (console vs jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

As you see in your prints you have

```
.....
[Pipeline] echo
Hello, false.
....
```

and then you try to do

```
for (build in job.builds) {
    def log = build.log
    if (log.contains('hey')) {
        println "${job.name}: ${build.id}"
    }
}
```

where your `job = false`, so you try to do `false.builds`, that doesn't exists.

Proof `job` before for and you should be ok.

Comment: Yes the issue is already with def job, but I don't see what is wrong there? The command above in comment works. What do you mean with prof job before?

Comment: if it is not false then do the `for` (prof was a typo :D)

Comment: But it shouldn't be false. In the console it's printing everything right.

Comment: can it be a permission issue? like here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41804